# How to round to specific, predefined numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to round a number to either 0, 25, 50, 75 or 100, in python 3. There are other threads with similar problems as this but I can't wrap my head around them.

I tried rounding the numbers by comparing the differences, which I probably did wrong. (This code is unfinished, I didn't continue when I realised the start of it doesn't work)

```
Position = int(input())

RC1 = 25 - Position
RC2 = 50 - Position
RC3 = 75 - Position

if (RC1 < RC2):
    Position = 25
if (RC2 < RC3):
    Position = 50
```

I wanted it to output the number which it was closest to. eg. 20 turns into 25, 42 turns into 50 etc.

Comment: Are your "steps" always going to be evenly spaced?

Comment: What _exactly_ does "round" mean in this context?

Comment: What I meant was it would leap to the number closest to it. Not really rounding. Here are some examples:

4 >>> 0
12 >>> 0 
16 >>> 25
22 >>> 25

And so on, with the base number being whatever, for every multiple of 25 up until 100. Its already been solved though, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use division and round to map number to closest position :

```
num = int(input())

Position= (round(num/25)*25)

print(Position)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this to determine which two values in a predefined `VALUES` list the input value lies between, and then the one its closest to. Note this approach makes no assumptions about the values in the list except that they're in ascending order (allowing them to be **unequally** spaced):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


VALUES = 0, 25, 50, 75, 100

posn = int(input("Enter position: "))

for lo, hi in pairwise(VALUES):
    if lo <= posn <= hi:
        if posn-lo < hi-posn:
            posn = lo
        else:
            posn = hi
        break
else:
    raise ValueError('A position of {} is out of range'.format(posn))

print('rounded position:', posn)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I feel like this can be done more efficiently through clever use of the `bisect` module... Not sure exactly how though.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks. Yes, it could probably be done with `bisect`, too—which might be faster (and worth using) if there were a really large number of possible values. I suggest you give it a try and post your own answer!

Comment: @martineau: `if position in range(VALUES[0], VALUES[-1]); print(position); else print("out of range")` might be useful. +1

Comment: @l'L'l: Good point. Yes, I probably should have handled the case when the position value is out of range—but think there's an better way in the sense that it doesn't require pre-checking every value...see update.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def round_func(position):
    VALUES = 25, 50, 75, 100
    result = 100
    if position < 0:
        return -1
    for i in VALUES:
        if position < i:
            result = i if i - position < 25 - (i - position) else i - 25
            break
    return result

print(round_func(int(input())))
```